# UnicodeDecodeError : web service to register in database

Tags: python-2.7, web-services, robotframework

I'm trying to develop a web service to register in database

```
${wsDefinition} Set Variable WSDL
${url} | Set Variable | URL
Create Soap Client | ${wsDefinition}
Set Location | ${url}
# Construire le message Soap
${XML} | set variable | <?xml version="1.0" ?> ............
<zia:Equipement>Téléphone</zia:Equipement>......</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
${message} | Create Raw Soap Message | ${XML}
# Appel WS
${methode} | set variable | CreationMajLocation
${Résult} | Call Soap Method | ${methode} | ${message}
```

I have an error because of "é".
FAIL : UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2176: ordinal not in range(128)
I can not find a solution to save this character in base. Can you help me?
Thank you

Comment: which statement is giving you that error?

Comment: In which encoding did you save your Robot File?